# How to apply range in datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, html, datetime

I am having below code in angular view page to apply date range.

```
<input type="text" 
       ui-options="{format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY'}"
       min-date="02/10/86"
       max-date="today" 
       ui-jp="datetimepicker"
       class="form-control">
```

and it is not working.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you had thought of using angular-material-datepicker? If so i can give you working plunker

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked please share your plunker

Comment: see http://plnkr.co/edit/zfY0azlAhD2MjOKm16qy?p=info if it helps you, i will share it as an answer.

Comment: I am sorry , it will completely change my UI and pattern. It would be good if it is for bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

Comment: Can you please add a plnkr/fiddle?